# What is wrong with this php while loop which keeps the page from loading?

Tags: php

I am trying to use a while loop to echo out all the student id's that belong to one account number. While the given below code executes fine when I remove the while loop, it  gives no output with the while loop, and the browser page keeps loading. Here is the code:

```
include "database.php";
$q = $_REQUEST["student_id"];

$q = strtolower($q);
$trimmed = trim($q);
$query4 = "select student_id from acc_details where account_no= (select account_no from acc_details where student_id = $trimmed)";
while ( $arr1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $query4))) {
    extract($arr1);
    echo "<h1> $student_id </h1>";
    //  I want to echo out some html output here
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the query? You're fetching a `student_id` that you already have as a parameter. It seems pointless, to me.
Also, I'm not sure `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` exists

Comment: @Uby, There is some point behind this query. The subquery gives the 'account number' of the ($_)REQUESTed student id and the main query will fetch all the student id's belonging to that account number. I need all those student id's that belong to the account number of the requested student id.. hope that makes some sense. :)

Comment: Your query is open to SQL Injections...  Never put user input dircetly into your queries. Always escape the input first, or preferably use prepared statements.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() exists because the code works fine without the while loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your suggestion. I'm actually putting here the minimum required code to save your valuable time while answering my question. I do pay attention to code vulnerability, but kindly address my above concern first.

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest that you present the actuall code instead of a rewrite. It's hard for us to help you find problems/bugs if we haven't seen the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

> it gives no output with the while loop, and the browser page keeps loading.

**Solution:**

Look at the following statement carefully,

```
while ( $arr1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $query4))) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is, in each iteration of while loop you're executing your query, and that's why while loop keep on executing, it never ends. Execute your query outside of while loop and take the result set to loop through it, like this:

```
include "database.php";
$q = $_REQUEST["student_id"];

$q = strtolower($q);
$trimmed = trim($q);
$query4 = "select student_id from acc_details where account_no IN (select account_no from acc_details where student_id = {$trimmed})";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query4);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: May I know the reason of this downvote, that too after 3 months?